# Updating TextView with timer onTick after leaving and returning to activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I'm writing a workout app and am trying to implement a rest timer in the `Train` activity. `CountDownTimer` located within `Train` and is called when the user presses a start button.

```
public CountDownTimer createTimer(long timerDuration) {

    Log.d("new timer duration:", "value: " + timerDuration);
    return new CountDownTimer(timerDuration, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            secondsLeftOnTimer = progress;  // update variable for rest of app to access

            // Update the output text
            breakTimerOutput.setText(secondsToString(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() { // Play a beep on timer finish
            breakTimerOutput.setText(secondsToString(timerDurationSeconds));
            playAlertSound();  // TODO: Fix the delay before playing beep.
        }
    }.start();
}
```

The timer works, as long as the user stays in the `Train` activity. If you switch to another activity, the timer continues to run in the background (the beep still occurs), which is what I want. If you go back to the Train activity, however, the `breakTimerOutput` TextView is no longer updated by `onTick`.

How can I "reconnect" `breakTimerOutput` to `onTick` when the user re-enters the `Train` activity?

[Here is the full code for the activity, just in case.](https://gist.github.com/minorsecond/14f5e0066ed8ad2a54c91f68d3273d35)

Comment: Have you consider onPause and onResume of your Train Activity?

Comment: I haven't, but that's an idea. Would I essentially be storing the timer when leaving the activity? I'm new to Android programming so I'm a little rusty on how one would typically handle something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest to keep the timer inside a `Service` and use `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the tick to update the `TextView` in your `TrainActivity`.

You need to start the `CountDownTimer` from the `Service`. So in the `onCreate` method of your `Service` you need to initialize a `LocalBroadcastManager`.

```
broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
```

So on each tick on your timer (i.e. `onTick` method), you might consider calling a function like this.

```
static final public String UPDATE_TIME = "UPDATE_TIME";
static final public String UPDATED_TIME = "UPDATED_TIME";

public void updateTextView(String time) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(UPDATE_TIME);
    if(time != null)
        intent.putExtra(UPDATED_TIME, time);
    broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Now in your `TrainActivity` create a `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.copa);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String time = intent.getStringExtra(YourService.UPDATED_TIME);
            // Update your TextView here.
        }
    };
}
```

And additionally you need to register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver), 
        new IntentFilter(YourService.UPDATE_TIME)
    );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good. I'll give it a shot. Am I correct in assuming that the code in your last stanza goes in `Train` activity?

Comment: Yes, the `Receiver` and the `onStart` and `onStop` belongs to `TrainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks! Lastly, I'm to define `receiver` as `BroadcastReceiver receiver`, correct? Doing so seems to cause an issue with your last bit of code, `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver), new IntentFilter(BreakTimer.UPDATE_TIME);`

Comment: Yes. You need to create a variable first which is named `receiver`.

Comment: I hate to bug you. I really appreciate your help, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've added the code for the countdown timer to the service but cannot figure out how to start it from the activity. I've never used a service so I don't really know how to access it.

[Here's the service](https://gist.github.com/minorsecond/03e392dc8a74462fe4fb9cf3a31e197d).